# Replace all occurences of one word in string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
"Tag: tie, Tag: ball, Tag: honey"
```

I want to replace "Tag: " with "" so that I have:

```
tie, ball, honey
```

I think I should use re.sub but I cannot write proper regular expression.

How do I achieve that result?

Comment: A simple string replace doesn't work?

Comment: [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
s = "Tag: tie, Tag: ball, Tag: honey"
print s.replace("Tag: ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use replace:

```
s="Tag: tie, Tag: ball, Tag: honey"
print s.replace("Tag:","")
```

Comment: Should be "Tag: " I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tag:\s*
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.

```
re.sub(r"Tag:\s*","",x)
```

here x is your input string.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/17

Answer (score 0):

Try this générique solution

```
  (?<=: )[^,]+
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/NwHBmK5rgI)